# How to modify the caption style in the subcaption package?

Tags: tables, captions

I was just using the subcaption package for the first time and I don't know how can I modify the format of the subtable captions. I want my subtable captions to be 1a, 1b, 1c and so on. The letters (a, b, c...) must not be capital and I don't need any brackets/interpunction in the caption.

Since this was my first time using the package, I copied someone else's code from this site, and it does not create the type of the output that I want. The problem is that I don't know how to change it. Here is what I have copied:

```
\usepackage{subcaption}

\DeclareCaptionSubType*[Alph]{table}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{mystyle}{Table~\bothIfFirst{#1}{ ̃}#2}
\captionsetup[subtable]{labelformat=mystyle}
```

This, however, creates the output in the format 1.A, 1.B, 1.C etc., which is not what I want.

If I delete last three lines of code, then in the text where I use `\ref` to refer to the table, I do see what I want - 1a, 1b and so on, but the caption of the table itself includes just the descriptive, text part of the caption and not the label. So I am wondering how can I format this in the way I want it?

Comment: As always one this site please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. That makes it a lot easier to see what exactly you're trying and provide help.

Comment: I am trying to learn how this works on a broader level and not just specifically for the table that I have. I want a generic solution which utilizes these commands that I've pasted in the question and which works regardless of how the table itself looks like. Oftentimes questions on these sites find a workaround to achieve the same desired output without addressing the core of the question itself, which is something I want to avoid. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: That is not the pojnt, when people see a question like this where they cannot just copy the example and test as is, most people will pass on the question and you are less likely to get any help.

Comment: Sadly what you say is indeed true, but I still stand by my argumentation line.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thesubcaption}{...}` will affect both the caption and `\ref`.  [labelformat-...] **only** afffects `\ref`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will produce the `1a, 1b,...` labeling as requested:

`labelformat=simple` will suppress the parents; and

`\renewcommand{\thesubtable}{\thetable\alph{subtable}}` will build the subtable labels as `<table number><subtable number>`, the first in arabic format and the second in alphabetical format.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\DeclareCaptionSubType*{table}
\captionsetup[subtable]{labelformat=simple}% no parens  
\renewcommand{\thesubtable}{\thetable\alph{subtable}} % added <<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht!]
        \centering
        \begin{subtable}{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            a&b\\
            c&d
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{sub one}
        \end{subtable}  
        \begin{subtable}{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            a&b\\
            c&d
        \end{tabular}
            \caption{sub two}
        \end{subtable}
        \caption{Two sub--tables caption}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{subtable}{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            w&x\\
            y&z
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{}\label{subt:t2a}
    \end{subtable}  
    \begin{subtable}{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            w&x\\
            y&z
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{}\label{subt:t2b}
    \end{subtable}
    \caption{ As shown in \ref{subt:t2a}  and in \ref{subt:t2b}...}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```