# How to add the word "Table" to subtable caption in subtable?

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, captions

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/660712/how-to-modify-the-caption-style-in-the-subcaption-package/660761#660761) and I will be using the table provided in the answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\DeclareCaptionSubType*{table}
\captionsetup[subtable]{labelformat=simple}% no parens  
\renewcommand{\thesubtable}{\thetable\alph{subtable}} % added <<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht!]
        \centering
        \begin{subtable}{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            a&b\\
            c&d
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{sub one}
        \end{subtable}  
        \begin{subtable}{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            a&b\\
            c&d
        \end{tabular}
            \caption{sub two}
        \end{subtable}
        \caption{Two sub--tables caption}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{subtable}{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            w&x\\
            y&z
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{}\label{subt:t2a}
    \end{subtable}  
    \begin{subtable}{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            w&x\\
            y&z
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{}\label{subt:t2b}
    \end{subtable}
    \caption{ As shown in \ref{subt:t2a}  and in \ref{subt:t2b}...}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Which produces a table like this (again taken from the answer):

[image]

However, what I want is that the subtables have a word "Table" in the caption and that there are no captions of their parent tables. Additionaly, I would like to insert a period after the table ID in the caption, but not when the table is referred to in the text. Here is a schematic of what I would like, made in Word:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following meet your formatting needs?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{myformat}{\tablename\ #2}
\captionsetup[subtable]{labelformat=myformat,labelsep=period}  
\renewcommand{\thesubtable}{\thetable\alph{subtable}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@subtable{} % no prefix string in cross-references
\makeatletter

\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref} % optional, for '\cref' macro

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering

\begin{subtable}{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc} a&b\\c&d \end{tabular}
\caption{Sub one} \label{tab:xx}
\end{subtable}  
\begin{subtable}{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc} e&f\\g&h \end{tabular}
\caption{Sub two} \label{tab:yy}
\end{subtable} 
 
\end{table}

As shown in \cref{tab:xx,tab:yy}, \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks, I accepted your answer. I just have a side question - it's excellent how `\cref` already creates the word "tables" in the text without having to write it. I was wondering if it's possible to make the "T" in "tables" capital, so that it says "As shown in Tables 1a and 1b..."

Comment: @J.Doe - You're most welcome. To capitalize the first letter in the cross-reference, use `\Cref` instead of `\cref`.